# How does property access works and what does the following line do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I've found following code at JS tutorial page and I'm quite unsure what does it do and how it work. Can you please explain what is it for and what it does?

---

// Source is : https://javascript.info/property-accessors

```
let user = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
  },

  set fullName(value) {
    [this.name, this.surname] = value.split(" "); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }
};
```

// set fullName is executed with the given value.

```
user.fullName = "Alice Cooper";

alert(user.name); // Alice
alert(user.surname); // Cooper
```

Comment: `value.split` creates a list with two elements and the elements are unpacked in `[this.name, this.surname]` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: it's just a definiton of a custom setter and getter for fullName property

Comment: The split part turns `"Alice Cooper"` into an array of strings, using a space as separator: `["Alice", "Cooper"]`. This is used to set `.name` and `.surname` using destructuring. Property access means that assinging something using `=` will not simply set the value but run the function declared with `set`, allowing you to do other things in addition or instead.

Comment: Getter and setters are called when the property is read or written. It is very helpful sometimes.

Comment: Thnak you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value.split` creates a list with two elements (in this special case `"Alice Cooper"` => `["Alice", "Cooper"]`) and the elements are unpacked into `[this.name, this.surname]`

`this.name` contains the first element of the array and `this.surname` contains the second element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
user.fullName = "Alice Cooper";
```

Calls the `set fullName` of `user`:

```
set fullName(value) {
    [this.name, this.surname] = value.split(" "); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Which then does a `.split` to the given string "Alice Cooper", dividing it into an array by the space in the string. So the result of `"Alice Cooper".split(" ")` is an array `["Alice", "Cooper"]`.

This array is then immediately [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into the `user` object's `name` and `surname` properties.